# Intellij IDEA doesn't see plugin module

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, configuration, module, intellij-plugin

I was trying to test some of open source plugins from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/). But I can't run/debug any of them because Intellij IDEA doesn't see plugin module. It says: `Run Configuration Error: No plugin module specified for configuration.` I tried a lot of different tricks, but nothing worked.

Comment: Do you have the *Plugin DevKit* plugin enabled?

Comment: Yes, I have this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a way to debug the plugin (I get that error for a plugin I am developing when I try to use the Plugin run configuration).

If you simply want to run the plugin, you can build the distribution XML file locally using the task provided by the plugin to do so. `gradle tasks` should list the available tasks. For my project (which uses [gradle-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) to provide IntelliJ plugin development integration in gradle), this task is:

```
gradle buildPlugin
```

You can then use the "Install plugin from disk..." option in the Settings > Plugin page of an IntelliJ instance.

The gradle-intellij-plugin integration also provides the:

```
gradle runIdea
```

task that starts a new IntelliJ instance in a sandboxed configuration with the plugin installed.